# Extracting scraped BeautifulSoap HTML data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoap and Python to scrape data from [this website](https://www.alilauro.it) 
Using *find_all* I've extracted table rows in a table, now I would like to  extract the table data for each row and add each data row them as row in an array. For example:

```
[12:55, Beverello, Ischia, http://alilauronew.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c 
/npgres.exe?PM=BM;...., ....]
```

Any help on how to do that are welcome. 
This is an example of the extracted data:

```
   [<tr class="grey1">
        <td class="orario">12:55</td>
        <td class="aL">Beverello</td>
        <td class="aL">Ischia</td>
        <td>
            <div class="circle green">
               <span class="tt-container">
                   <span class="tt-arrow"></span>
                   <span class="tt-text">corsa regolare</span>
               </span>
            </div>
        </td>
       <td><a href="http://alilauronew.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c     
            /npgres.exe?PM=BM" target="_blank"><img src="/templates 
            /frontend/images/carrello.png"/></a></td>
 </tr>
   [<tr class="grey1">
        <td class="orario">14:45</td>
        <td class="aL">Ischia</td>
        <td class="aL">Beverello</td>
        <td>
            <div class="circle green">
               <span class="tt-container">
                   <span class="tt-arrow"></span>
                   <span class="tt-text">corsa regolare</span>
               </span>
            </div>
        </td>
       <td><a href="http://alilauronew.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c     
            /npgres.exe?PM=BM" target="_blank"><img src="/templates 
            /frontend/images/carrello.png"/></a></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fully working example, `data` list will contain all what you wanted without noise(empty strings etc)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://www.alilauro.it').text
bs = BeautifulSoup(response)

data = []
# I don't want to scrape the headers, so I'm slicing the list, emitting the first element
no_header = list(bs.select('#partenze tr'))[1:]
for tr in no_header:
    td = tr.select('td')
    data.append({
        'ORA':td[0].text,
        'PARTENZA DA':td[1].text,
        'ARRIVO A':td[2].text,
        'ACQUISTA':td[4].select('a')[0].attrs['href']
    })

print(data)
```

Notes:

- I used `requests` library to make the http request, you could use whatever you want
- I used css selectors, using bs's built in `select` just a personal choice

Comment: Great solution and efficient. I had done such a convoluted piece of code just to remove the header. Do you recommend any online resource to learn more on BS/ webscraping? I've just realised I really need to learn more.

Comment: There is bunch of resources online, but I can not give better advice then just keep practice. Skipping the first element of a list this way is just something you learn along the way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<tr class="grey1">
        <td class="orario">12:55</td>
        <td class="aL">Beverello</td>
        <td class="aL">Ischia</td>
        <td>
            <div class="circle green">
               <span class="tt-container">
                   <span class="tt-arrow"></span>
                   <span class="tt-text">corsa regolare</span>
               </span>
            </div>
        </td>
       <td><a href="http://alilauronew.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c
            /npgres.exe?PM=BM" target="_blank"><img src="/templates
            /frontend/images/carrello.png"/></a></td>
 </tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
row=[td.text.strip() for td in soup.findAll('td')]
print(row)
```

Output:

```
['12:55', 'Beverello', 'Ischia', 'corsa regolare', '']
```